# In Java, how do you check if a float variable is null?

Tags: java, android, variables, null

It seems that when it comes to *value.getFloat("Value_Quotient", quotient_Float)==null*, it encounters a problem. How do I fix this?

```
private void Store() {
    quotient_Float = posture_error/time;
    if(value.getFloat("Value_Quotient", quotient_Float)==null || quotient_Float < value.getFloat("Value_Quotient", quotient_Float))
    {
        editor.putFloat("Value_Quotient", quotient_Float);
        editor.commit();
    }           
}
```

Comment: A `float` cannot be `null`. A `Float` can be `null`. Is your variable primitive type or reference type?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`float` is a `primitive` data type and not an `object`. null check is used for objects. For primitives you should use the default values check. For float the default value is 0.0f.

Comment: [primitive data type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Answer (score 5):

There is also a [Float](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html) class that you can use. The `Float` object can be checked for `null` as its an object representation of a `float` data type. A `Float` object is represented by a capitol F, and the `float` data type has a small f. Java preforms autoboxing, which means that you can easily switch back and fourth between the two, i.e:

```
float number = 0.56f;
Float object = number;
```

Or the other way around:

```
Float object = new Float(1.43);
float number = object;
```

You can also pass a `Float` object into a method where a `float` data type is expected, or the other way around.

If checking for the default value doesnt work for whatever reason, this will allow you to check a `Float` for null.

```
if (object != null) {
    // do what you want to do
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some points that might be useful(Java 8).

Float object can be assigned to a float primitive. Then float primitive can be 0 checked like this:

```
    Float floatObj = new Float(0);
    float floatPrim = floatObj;

    if (floatPrim == 0) {
        System.out.println("floatPrim  is 0"); // will display message
    }
```

However if your Float object is null, than assigning it to a primitive will cause NPE

```
    Float floatObj = null;
    float floatPrim = floatObj; //NPE
```

So be careful here

One more thing, apparently you can use == operator on Float object, since autounboxing happens.

```
    Float floatObj = new Float(0.0f);

    if (floatObj == 0) {
        System.out.println("floatObj  is 0"); // will work 
    }
```